# How to fix "Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Operation not found: CreateCollection"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am setting up a Facial Detection program in AWS rekognition, but for some reason, I am getting an error when trying to run the `CreateCollection` method.

I have already installed Composer, and installed aws-sdk-php using Composer.

When I run this script:

```php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'profile' => 'default',
'version' => 'latest',
'region' => 'us-east-2'
]);

$collection = $s3->createCollection([
        'CollectionId' => '0'
])
```

I get this error
`Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Operation not found: CreateCollection in /path/to/AwsClient.php:248`

Ideally, I would not be encountering this error, and instead be creating a Collection in which I could store photos. What steps should I take to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using RekognitionClient, not S3Client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Rekognition.RekognitionClient.html